# docker with wildfly HA in domain mode

Tags: jakarta-ee, docker, wildfly-8

With docker, you always have to create a new image when you want to do redeployment. How does this fit with wildfly high availability mode in domain mode?

In domain mode with host controller, you simply deploy your application to the host controller, and the host controller will take care of propagating the deployment to all slaves, making sure that the entire cluster is still up and can serve request, regardless of current deployment status.

How would this work with docker, if i have to create an image of wildfly with the new release, and then restart the host controller? Host controller shouldn't be down.

Or in this scenario, i should just ignore docker altogether, considering it is fast becoming a programmer's paradise in the deployment arena.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve zero-downtine for your service a common solution is first starting a container with the new image, then after everything important has been migrated to the new container(the old container has no more open connections etc.) you can shutdown the old container.

Comment: Why do you think so? If this sounds like a problem to you, maybe your application is not ready to be dockerized yet?